# create read/write environment using named pipes

Tags: bash, redirect, system-verilog

I am using RedHat EL 4. I am using Bash 3.00.15.

I am writing SystemVerilog and I want to emulate stdin and stdout. I can only use files as the normal stdin and stdout is not supported in the environment. I would like to use named pipes to emulate stdin and stdout.

I understand how to create a to_sv and from_sv file using mkpipe, and how to open them and use them in SystemVerilog.

By using "cat > to_sv" I can output strings to the SystemVerilog simulation. But that also outputs what I'm typing in the shell.

I would like, if possible, a single shell where it acts almost like a UART terminal. Whatever I type goes directly out to "to_sv", and whatever is written to "from_sv" gets printed out.

If I am going about this completely wrong, then by all means suggest the correct way! Thank you so much,

Nachum Kanovsky

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: You can output to a named pipe and read from an other one in the same terminal. You can also disable keys to be echoed to the terminal using `stty -echo`.

```
mkfifo /tmp/from
mkfifo /tmp/to
stty -echo
cat /tmp/from & cat > /tmp/to
```

Whit this command everything you write goes to `/tmp/to` and is not echoed and everything written to `/tmp/from` will be echoed.

**Update**: I have found a way to send every chars inputed to the /tmp/to one at a time. Instead of `cat > /tmp/to` use this command:

```
while IFS= read -n1 c;
do  
   if [ -z "$c" ]; then 
      printf "\n" >> /tmp/to; 
   fi; 
   printf "%s" "$c" >> /tmp/to; 
done
```

Comment: What I would like is both directions within a single shell if possible. Like a UART terminal would work. What I type shouldn't be echoed back. I believe with the cat > /tmp/a solution, the characters are all echoed back.

Comment: @user832745 I updated my answer. At first I did not understand correctly what you needed. May be because I have never used a real terminal, only terminal emulator. The [UART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver/transmitter) thing did not mean much to me either, may be because I have a software background more than an electronical/hardware background. Now I hope my answer does what you describe.

Comment: That was very helpful! Thank you. It is working now. Can the characters be sent unbuffered? Currently what I type in the terminal, which goes to /tmp/to, the letters are only sent once I press enter. How can I get each keypress to go without being buffered?

Comment: Its hard to find a way of sending every keys one at a time. `cat`, `dd` seam to wait for the `\n` even if you manage to read only one char at a time using `read -n1 c; echo "$c"`, it does not handle spaces or newlines. Ill check again see if I can find. May be a curse software? or a terminal like minicom will do.

Comment: I have updated my solution to send every chars one at a time to the output.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `exec` as in:

```
exec > to_sv
exec < from_sv
```

See sections **19.1.** and **19.2**. in the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide - I/O Redirection](http://kaneda.bohater.net/faq/abs-guide/io-redirection.html)

Comment: I have just tried it very quickly. It doesn't yet seem to be working for me. What I tried is 'exec > to_sv &' and then 'exec < from_sv &'. I then went to another shell and typed 'cat to_sv'. This just exited, and caused the exec > to_sv job from the other shell to exit also.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cat /tmp/from &` you may use `tail -f /tmp/from &` (at least here on Mac OS X 10.6.7 this prevented a deadlock if I `echo` more than once to `/tmp/from`).

Based on Lynch's code:

```
# terminal window 1
(
rm -f /tmp/from /tmp/to
mkfifo /tmp/from
mkfifo /tmp/to
stty -echo
#cat -u /tmp/from & 
tail -f /tmp/from & 
bgpid=$!
trap "kill -TERM ${bgpid}; stty echo; exit" 1 2 3 13 15
while IFS= read -n1 c;
do  
  if [ -z "$c" ]; then 
    printf "\n" >> /tmp/to
  fi; 
  printf "%s" "$c" >> /tmp/to
done
)

# terminal window 2
(
tail -f /tmp/to & 
bgpid=$!
trap "kill -TERM ${bgpid}; stty echo; exit" 1 2 3 13 15
wait
)

# terminal window 3
echo "hello from /tmp/from" > /tmp/from
```