# Connecting two running terminals Linux

Tags: linux

I have two terminals running on Linux. Lets call them `T1` and `T2`.
Now I want to connect `stdout` of `T1` to `T2` and `stdout` of `T2` to `T1`.

I have googled redirecting `stdout` to another terminal but came up empty handed.

Comment: You may try named pipes. Have a look at this question (see the answer with the named pipes): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640493/redirect-the-stdin-to-come-from-a-different-terminal-using-bash. It deals with stdin, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Also take a look at `socat`.